# AS3 How to create double sided MovieClip which when rotation shows the other side as well?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, graphics, computational-geometry

I have a movie clip which has two frames. On the first frame I have the front side and on the second I have the back. I am rotating the MovieClip by rotationX,  rotationY,  rotationZ properties.

I want to display the frame 2 when the MovieClip rotates. Please help. I dont want to use PaperVision class. Also, please consider the Perspective View of the scene.

Sometimes, the MovieClip might not only be dependent on rotation. It is also equally dependent on the position (only in Perspective View).

Thanks for considering my question.

Regards,
Sanket

PS: Please check the problem here
http://sanket.info/as3/problem.gif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to add to the existing solutions, here are some ready made utilities:

- [Thibault Imbert's SideDetector](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=468)
- [Senocular's IsFrontFacing](http://www.senocular.com/flash/actionscript/?file=ActionScript_3.0/com/senocular/display/isFrontFacing.as)
- [Soulwire's Double Sided 3D Plane](http://blog.soulwire.co.uk/code/open-source/two-sided-planes-in-flash-player-10)

[image: Soulwire's Double Sided 3D Plane]

HTH

Comment: lol, i like senocular's method of globalization points.  i have thought of something like that to test if a MovieClip is flipped horizontally.  However i wouldn't have thought it would work for 3d.  This makes my day!  good find George.

Comment: Thanks a lot George! :-) This works really great. I liked Senocular's method.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you want to determine which side you see based on the rotation and the perspective angle combined.

rotation you already know how to read.

and it looks like the perspective angle is based on only a change in x (based on your image)

in game terms, this would be like seeing through the eyes of a hero that can only step left and right, but not forwards backwards or turning.  Please confirm.

if thats the case, i recommend finding the perspective angle with something like this.

this is 2d math as if viewing your camera(as hero) and your pic from overhead.  and finding the angle between them.

```
//find difference between hero and pic positions  (delta means difference or change)
var deltaPt:Point = new Point(pic.x - hero.x, pic.y - hero.y);
//find angle between hero and pic, then convert to degrees from radians
var angle:Number = Math.atan2(deltaPt.y, deltaPt.x) * 180 / Math.PI

var testAngle:Number = pic.rotation + angle;
trace("angle: "+angle);
trace("testAngle: "+testAngle);
```

check if those traces are anywhere near what your expecting to see.

perhaps angle needs to be negative instead of positive, or offset by 90º or something  (i tend to guess and check this a bit, sorry for the slop)

if your hero is also able to rotate... it may get more complicated, or it might just involve adding the hero's rotation to the mix, I haven't thought that part through just yet.

once you get it adjusted right it should end in something like this, which I'm sure you already know.

```
if(testAngle > 90){gotoAndStop(2)}
else{gotoAndStop(1)};
```

hope that helps some.

Comment: i suppose i should note that since the math is as if from an overhead view, my y is probably your z.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link.

http://codingfiend.com/examples/greeting_card/

Rather than using two frames, make your front and back as two movieclips on one frame.  Place them on top of each other, front side on top, and flip the backside horizontally.  I used this ENTER_FRAME event to track rotation and show and hide the front of the card.  I start the event when clicking the front of the card, track the tween and kill the event when its open.  Perhaps you could also track position as well as rotation to accomplish what you are looking for.

```
protected function oef(evt:Event):void
{
    var rot:Number = Math.round(_front.rotationY);

    if(rot >= 0 && rot <= 89)
    {
        _front.outside.visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
    _front.outside.visible = false;
    }           
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my problem is little more complicated. Consider a plane parallel to YZ-plane. If its at the center, then we see only a vertical line. Without any rotation, if it moves towards the left then we see one side of the plane and if it moves right then we see the other side. How to determine that?

Comment: In the same ENTER_FRAME you could track the x of the plane if moving horizontal and the y of the plane if moving vertical.  Compare those values to your stage width or height to see if its left/right or above/below center and hide/show the appropriate side.

Comment: Gimme a sec, I'm making an example.

Comment: We need to consider PerspectiveProjection class and manipulate the same with the currecnt 3D Matrix to get the result. Its not just X-coordinate. There can be rotationX, rotationY, rotationZ and X, Y, Z positioning. I may change the center of projection anytime in the program and it should reflect the same in the output.

Comment: In the example, the rotation concept works very close to perfect. But it has got errors. Place your mouse at the center of the sphere and then look at the square at the top and bottom poles of the sphere. They're different. Both of them should show the back actually.

Comment: yes, the approach is not perfect.  In my greeting card example the frame rate must be set high enough or you see the switch happening at the wrong time or inconsistently.  This was the only methodology I could come up with as player 10 3d does not allow for a double sided plane.

Comment: it seems like its off by a small amount also when observing the squares on the rows as well.  They appear to switch a little bit early.  could this be solved by a small hack so to speak?  add or subtract a little from the calculation?  Not the most elegant suggestion but it might work.