# Flash actionscript Double-sided object that rotates after x amount of seconds

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've been googling my butt off and have been able to find bits and pieces (mainly how to rotate an object in Flash) but not the portion about maintaining images on both sides.

I would like to create a MC that has a picture on the front-side, and when rotated horizontally the front-side image will fade according to the transition and the back-side image will appear.

Can someone help or point me to a tutorial that can help me achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want to 3D rotate an image on the z-axis?

Comment: Not necessarily a 3D image, just a regular 2-d image (like a solitaire card) but instead of a king of hearts and some design on the back I want to incorporate my own images.

Comment: why not using google: http://www.google.com/search?q=3d+rotate+z+axis+actionscript+image&oq=3d+rotate+z+axis+actionscript+image

Comment: I can already rotate the image, but the problem appears when it rotates. If the front of my image says "hello" when it rotates I don't want to see "olleh" i want to see whatever i set as the backside of the image. lol

Comment: In 2D you can check the transform matrix(MC.transform.matrix.a) and if the .a property is less than 0 (e.g. pefectly flipped horizontally would be -1) then overlay your 'fipped' content. In 3D have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005774/as3-how-to-create-double-sided-movieclip-which-when-rotation-shows-the-other-side/5015463#5015463)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this recipe, StageFlip, a long time ago. A quick read makes me cringe a little since there are quite a few things I would change (including not using the Flash tween engine) but the lighting adjustment during the animation does add realism (see the .swf file).

Comment: I was reading the source code (C# programmer), and I can see where the actual wording for "...side A/B..." is in the attached pdf, but when I look at the actionscript I only see references to side1/2. How/where is it pulling the side A/B from?

Comment: if i remember correctly, Side A/B are just the text i used on the sprite objects for each side.  "side1" / "side2" are the names of the instance variables within the class.  the Side A/B sprites are programatically created in the .fla in a frame script (*cringe*).  sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial on [Easy Breezy 3D Card Flip Effect with Flash, AS3 and Our Good Buddy TimelineMax](http://www.snorkl.tv/2010/12/easy-breezy-3d-card-flip-effect-with-flash-as3-and-our-good-buddy-timelinemax/) is what you need. They run through it simply and use Tweenlite which i recommend. You can easily add a delay to a tweenlite tween if you wish. Just check out there [Tweenlite docs](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/), and maybe do a find for "delay".

Answer (score 1):

Here's the general procedure:

1) Create 2 movie clips: one for the "front" and one for the "back". They should be the same size and both have their registration point TOP-CENTER or CENTER-CENTER.
2) Hide the "back" and set its rotation on the Y axis to -90.
3) When the animation starts, tween the "front" on the Y axis from 0 to 90.
4) Hide the "front" and show the "back".
5) Tween the "back" from -90 to 0 on the Y axis.