# How to make Collada model double sided in papervision3d

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, papervision3d

i have an animated collada  of envelope module that have an animation of opening itself

now for seeing both sides of the envelope i set the

```
      oneSide = false
```

i added for tests a ColorMaterial.

but what i want is to have 1 color in the outside faces and another color in the inside faces

and i can't figure it out how to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found some class that a very great men develop!!! that solove this:
here is a link to download it it the last post on the page:
http://papervision3d.758870.n4.nabble.com/How-to-get-DoubleSidedCompositeMaterial-working-w-Latest-PV3D-td781516.html#a781518

direct link:
http://papervision3d.758870.n4.nabble.com/file/n781518/customPV3D.zip

Answer (score 0):

A quick trick would be to clone the envelope model, have it at 1 unit apart on the Z axis from the original and set the back material.

Have a look at [this example](http://blog.onebyonedesign.com/actionscript/double-sided-plane-with-papervision/).

Anther way would be to check where the envelope's normal is pointing or use it's rotation to determine if it's facing forward or not, then update the material, or it's bitmap.

For more ideas on how to find out if a plane is facing the 'camera' or not have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005774/as3-how-to-create-double-sided-movieclip-which-when-rotation-shows-the-other-side/5015463#5015463). It's not papervision specific, but the principles can be applied with papervision as well.

Comment: i found the best simple solution check: http://papervision3d.758870.n4.nabble.com/How-to-get-DoubleSidedCompositeMaterial-working-w-Latest-PV3D-td781516.html#a781518

Comment: i know your tricks and they dont work when loading complex objects!